# Algorithmic analysis / comparing run-times of functions with different growth rates

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity

I have a homework problem:

If an algorithm takes 0.5 ms for an input size of 100, how long will it take for inputs of 500, 1,000 and 10,000 if it is:

1. Linear,
2. O(N log N),
3. Quadratic,
4. Cubic,
5. Exponential.

I understand the basic concepts here, I'm just unsure of how to approach the question mathematically. I'm tempted to simply calculate the amount of time it takes to do process each individual item of input (for instance, in a) I'll divide 0.5 by 100 to get .05, which I'll then multiply by 500, 1000 and 1000 to find how long it will take to process inputs of those sizes.

While this is simple for the linear calculations, and also pretty straightforward for quadratic and cubic ones, I don't quite understand how to apply this strategy to (N log N) or exponential functions: What value do I use as the base of the exponent?

For (N log N), is it as simple as calculating c = 100 * log(100) = 200; then calculating c = 500 * log(500) = 1349, which is 6.745 times 200, then multiplying 6.745 by .5 to arrive at 3.3725 as a final answer?

Comment: In these notions Log is of base 2 unless specified otherwise, the calculation you've made is the right approach but with the wrong base.

Comment: @Joni did I say it doesn't?

Comment: Whoops, a typo. I meant: the base does *not* matter, @RonTeller. Base 10, base 2, same result.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad exercise:

- It teaches you to extrapolate from a single datapoint.
- It teaches you to apply the results of asymptotic analysis where they can't be applied.

To expand on the latter, you cannot predict the performance of a system when given specific inputs based on an asymptotic bound because of hidden terms. Many algorithms have hidden constant and linear terms that dominate the run time for small input sizes like n=100.

But if you are supposed to ignore these facts, your approach is correct.

Comment: While true, if you make the (not wholly unreasonable) guess that n = 100 is large enough for the dominant growth term to emerge, you can make a reasonably educated guess.

Comment: Most CS homework problems I've seen are meaningless. Still need to do them to get a meaningful piece of paper to enter the real world and see how meaningless they all were.

Comment: @templatetypedef: If (e.g. CPU) caches matter 100 might actually be dominated by constant terms.

Comment: @WilliamGaul, what I mean is that the given information is not enough to solve the problem, *not* that it's not worth the time and effort to try to do it. This is a bad exercise problem in general: it teaches you that it's OK to extrapolate from a single data point and tells you to apply the results of asymptotic analysis where they cannot be applied.

Comment: @Joni Ah...in that case, very true.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the function's runtime is given by T(n). You can solve these problems by doing the following:

1. Write a general expression for T(n) in terms of the function's growth rate, given there is some hidden constant multiplier.  For example, for the n log n case, write T(n) = c n log n for some constant c.
2. Solve for c using the one data point you have; T(100) is given to you.
3. Plug in values of n as needed to estimate the runtime.

This works for any growth rate.

A quick note: "exponential" is not precise enough for you to make a meaningful estimate.  2^n and 100^n are both exponential but the latter grows significantly faster than the former.  In computer science, typically logs use base 2, though there's no general conventions for exponents.

Hope this helps!